# How can a client on a mobile device connect to localhost with a server running on a PC?

Tags: android, rest, server, localhost, client

I have a big problem because I have a pc with a little  amount of RAM and I can't use my RESTlet server on Eclipse and an Android client on Android Studio together... I read on the internet some solutions at my problem but maybe I wrong somethings because it doesn't work. How can I use the localhost (with or without the cable is the same) with my pc (for the server) and my phone (for the client) to debug and use my project?

Comment: What is a REST server on Eclipse? No idea. And how would an Android client run on Android Studio? Android clients run on Android devices or on emulators. Please reword your post and tell your setup first. What i think is that your pc acts as a server and on your Android device you have a client app. Pretty standard.

Comment: So your question should be: how can a client on an Android device connect with a server running on a pc?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [**ngrok**](https://ngrok.com/). It's a great addition to any developer's toolbox.

This app allows you to make your `localhost` accessible to the internet through a secure channel.

You'll download a small application for your PC, which will then give you a temporary and random URL, through which you can access the web server on your local machine.

This way, your phone will be able to reach your PC over WiFi, cell data, etc. You just need to have a way to configure the destination URL in your phone app to set it to the URL that **ngrok** gives you.

---

Another solution would be to create a Windows VM on any of the Cloud providers (such as AWS, Azure, Google, etc.), remote desktop into that machine, install Eclipse, copy your code and and run your API server there. And then use your own PC to run your Android simulator and point the destination URL to your VM's IP or domain name. This solution would be somewhat more complicated to set up and will require you to move your code around, expose the right ports, install a bunch of software on the VM, etc. Not to mention, this will probably cost you a little bit of money. So for testing and debugging purposes, that **ngrok** solution should work great.

Answer (score 0):

In your url instead of "localhost" copy and paste your PC ip v4 address.You can get it on Windows from command prompt ipconfig command